# MongoEngine - how to make sure document has been saved?

Tags: python, mongoengine

After defining a document, creating an instance and calling the save method on that instance, what is the best way to make sure the saving of the document succeeds?

Should I implement the post_save method, use try/except block, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save()` is a synchronous call:

```
Save the :class:`~mongoengine.Document` to the database. If the
document already exists, it will be updated, otherwise it will be
created. Returns the saved object instance.
```

Use `try/except` block to deal with errors.